# Importing an upgraded version of ExtJS into an existing project

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd, extjs6

I have an existing Java 1.8 web application that uses ExtJS 3.  I need to upgrade to ExtJS 6 - but I can't figure out how to do this.

All the documentation I've come up so far explains how to do it with an entirely new project.

So after downloading and installing Sencha Cmd 6 and downloading and unzipping ExtJS 6, the documentation says to run the following from the command line:

```
sencha -sdk /path/to/extjs/framework generate app AppName path/to/app
cd /path/to/app
sencha app watch
```

Only problem is this assumes I want to do a new app - and also because it seems to lock everything into that particular new project.

Can someone point me to some documentation on how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no automatic means of directly upgrading an ExtJS 3 app to ExtJS 6. The Sencha Cmd (the command line tool that you used to generate app) supports only ExtJS 4.1.1a and above [(citation)](https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/5.x/intro_to_cmd.html).

Most legacy applications written with ExtJS 3 and below are unstructured and did not have a framework-driven MVC. Depending on how big and complex your application is, an upgrade to ExtJS 6 can be as difficult as re-writing the application. The best approach is to start with a new ExtJS 6 application and migrate your existing application into the new one piece-by-piece, Here is the 
[Sencha Documentation](https://www.sencha.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-your-ext-js-3-4-apps-to-ext-js-6/) that shows an example of how to do it.